# Is there a way to detect if an app is "Scaled to Match iPad" versus "Optimize for Mac"

Tags: swift, mac-catalyst

Is there a way to detect either at runtime or compile time if a Mac Catalyst app is "Scaled to Match iPad" versus "Optimize for Mac".

The [Conditional Compilation Block](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/statements/#Conditional-Compilation-Block) suggests this info is not available at compilation time with a method similar to `targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)`.

The [Build settings reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/build-settings-reference#Targeted-Device-Families) says this info is in the TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY Info.plist entry, so perhaps I can get it from there at runtime.

This info isn't present in `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no compile-time check available. If you look at the build log when compiling a Swift file, there is no difference in the flags passed to the compiler between the two settings.

But as described in [Choosing a user interface idiom for your Mac app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/choosing_a_user_interface_idiom_for_your_mac_app), there is runtime check. This involves looking at the interface idiom from an appropriate trait collection or from `UIDevice userInterfaceIdiom`.

When you build as "Optimize for Mac" then you get the `.mac` idiom. When you build as "Scaled to Match iPad" then you get the `.ipad` idiom.

An example shown in the linked documentation is:

```swift
let childViewController: UIViewController
if traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == .mac {
    childViewController = MacOptimizedChildViewController()
} else {
    childViewController = ChildViewController()
}
```

There may be cases when you will want to wrap such code in a compiler check for `targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)` so the iOS code can use a different option from either Mac version.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the answer:

- If "Scaled to Match iPad" then UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom ==
  1
- If "Optimize for Mac" then UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == 5